# Getting jobId from inside of Batchlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsr352

I need get the jobId from inside of executing batchlet. Already, I'm able to get the jobId from the class that I am lanching the Batchlet, but not from inside of Batchlet.

`long jobId = job.start("BatchletName", parm);`

This sentence launch the Batchlet "BatchletName". Now, I need to get the jobId value from inside de class BatchletName.java:

```
@Dependent
@Named("BatchletName")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class BatchletName extends AbstractBatchlet {
    public String process() throws Exception {
        // I need jobId here
        return "";
    }    
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `javax.batch.runtime.context.JobContext` into your batchlet class, then call [JobContext.getJobName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/batch/runtime/context/JobContext.html#getJobName--) to get the job id.

```
import javax.batch.runtime.context.JobContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Dependent
@Named("BatchletName")
public class BatchletName extends AbstractBatchlet {
    @Inject
    JobContext jobContext;

    public String process() throws Exception {
        // I need jobId here

        String jobId = jobContext.getJobName();
        return "";
    }  
}
```